# Number of ways of dividing books into groups

Tags: combinatorics

There are $p+q$ different books on different topics in Mathematics. Then what is the number of ways in which the books can be divided into two groups of $p$ books and $q$ books ?

According to the answer it’s supposed to be $\binom{p+q}{q}$ But according to the question they haven’t mentioned which group of books , i.e. $p$ books or $q$ books should be formed first . So should the answer actually be $\frac{\binom{p+q}{q}}{2}$ in that case ?

Also given that $p$ is not equal to $q$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since they have not mentioned which group is first, it can be **either** $\binom{p+q}{q}$ **or** $\binom{p+q}{p}$. But note
$$\binom{p+q}{q}=\frac{(p+q)!}{q!(p+q-q)!}=\frac{(p+q)!}{q!p!}=\frac{(p+q)!}{(p+q-p)!p!}=\binom{p+q}{p}$$

Answer (score 2):

It does not matter which one you form first; choosing one group automatically leaves the other group remaining. A good way to visualise this is on Pascal's Triangle:

[image]

Each row $n$ of the triangle corresponds to the total number of books $n-1$, and the entries in each row designate the number of ways to choose $0,1,2,...,n$ books.

For example, there are $6$ books in total (use the $7^{th}$ row) and you want groups of $q=2$ books and $p=4$ books. The entries in the row gives the way to choose $0$ books, $1$ book, $2$ books, $3$ books, etc. So the $7^{th}$ row's third entry, $15$, corresponds to $q$. Notice that the fifth entry is the same, and corresponds to $p$. By the symmetry of the triangle, whichever group you choose first, the result will be the same.